# How to prevent foreign keys from messing up?

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys

This is how my tables look:

```
tableMembers | memberID as primary key

tableAddress | addressID as primary key references memberID

tableSubscription | subsID as primary key references memberID
```

This database is for a subscription site. Basically, if a row is inserted into tableMembers, a corresponding row is inserted to each of the other tables.

I set up foreign keys for the last two tables so I can access them in relation to tableMembers. Basically if I access a row from tableAddress I do:

```
SELECT * FROM tableAddress WHERE addressID = (SELECT memberID FROM tableMembers WHERE uname = 'John');
```

The problem with my setup is that, when synchronization of ID's gets messed up, foreign keys would no longer work. Say, when I insert a row into tableMembers and then tableSubscription becomes dysfunctional for few seconds for some weird reasons? Or in case of a user signing up (**latest memberID becomes = 2**), say he/she doesn't subscribe which leaves subsID (**which remains = 1**) unsynchronized with memberID. And later on, a new user signs up (**latest memberID becomes = 3**) and subscribes (**subsID becomes = 2**). That makes my query above obselete. How do I prevent this kind of scenario? Or please enlighten me if you think I don't understand the concept of foreign keys.

Comment: `tableAddress` and `tableSubscription` are setup to have one-to-one relationships with `tableMembers`.  Generally, one-to-one relationships are combined into a single table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that *only one of the tables have an autoincrementing id*. The others should get their id from the insert query, from the application code, to make sure they are for the correct member.

In pseudo-code:

1. User signs up and get an
   autoincremented id of 3.
2. Check the
   id with last_insert_id()
3. User
   subscribes to something. The id in
   the tableSubscription table should
   be set by your application code to
   the value you got earlier.